# Is there a way to make Chrome browser's scrollbar more visible?

Tags: google-chrome, internet, browser

They changed it a while ago and now it's really hard to see where you are on a page by looking at the scrollbar. Seriously what are they thinking...

Is there a way to change its color/contrast?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As I know, Google chrome scroll-bar is not customize-able manually. however you can use themes or skins or plugins. two of the best plugins are [Better Scrollbar](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/better-scrollbar/hllbomlnkhcgejgcjaidcodpnkefhjcg) and [Rescroller](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/rescroller/ddehdnnhjimbggeeenghijehnpakijod/related?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon). both of them lets you custom your scroll-bar.

Comment: Rescroller worked perfectly, and has a Github repository, which gives me more confidence in its honesty